# Distribute by vs Cluster by in spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hiveql

I have recently started working on spark, We always use cluster by to optimize the tables before joining but I wanted to know is there any scenario where we prefer distribute by over cluster by clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only difference between cluster by and distribute by is 
Distribute by only repartitions the data based on the expression while cluster by first repartitions that data and then sorts the data based on key in each partition.

Equivalent representations of cluster by and distribute by in dataframe api is as follows:
distribute by

> df.repartition($"key", 2)

cluster by

> df.repartition($"key", 2).sortWithinPartitions()

Both involves shuffle operation except cluster by has extra sorting operation.

Comment: thanks for the clarifying that out , but I wanted to know as if there is any real scenario/case where we will prefer distribute by over cluster by.

Comment: I could not recall any real scenario which i have worked on. But let's say you want to write the output of dataframe to disk in files and you want each content in each file to be sorted , you cold prefer to use cluster by . In case you don't care about sorting , you can go ahead with distribute by.